# Should a AppWidgetProvider disable itself in onDisabled callback?

Tags: android, widget

I found [com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider](http://codesearch.google.com/#ohAXAHj6Njg/src/com/android/settings/widget/SettingsAppWidgetProvider.java) disables itself in `onDisabled()` callback, and enables itself in `onEnabled()`.

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName("com.android.settings", ".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    Class clazz = com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider.class;
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName("com.android.settings", ".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

I think it is weird. If the last instance of "**Powre Control**"(The widget name of `SettingsAppWidgetProvider`) is removed, `onDisabled()` is called and this provider disables itself. How can it receive furthre broadcasts after it is disabled? If it can't receive any broadcasts anymore, the `ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED` will never be delivered to this provider and the `onEnabled()` callback will have no chance to be called, and then this provider will have no chance to reenable itself.

I have tried this "trick" in one of my onw widgets and found my `AppWidgetProvider` does not work any more after the last widget instance is removed.

Comment: I would expect this to behave as you discovered -- once the last app widget instance is removed, you cannot add new instances of the app widget. It is conceivable that this is tied to this being a firmware app widget or something, but it is definitely strange.